Package biblatex Error: Incompatible package 'natbib'
I am getting several errors on overleaf and the main one is:Package biblatex Error: Incompatible package 'natbib'. I know that probably natbib is loaded by one of my used packages which is incompatible with biblatex, but I don't know which package it is. I appreciate any help on this.
Here is the code to it:
    \documentclass[sn-mathphys-num]{sn-jnl}% Math and Physical 
%\usepackage[a6paper,margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}%
\usepackage{multirow}%
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}%
\usepackage{amsthm}%
\usepackage{mathrsfs}%
\usepackage[title]{appendix}%
\usepackage{xcolor}%
\usepackage{textcomp}%
\usepackage{manyfoot}%
\usepackage{algorithm}%
\usepackage{algorithmicx}%
\usepackage{algpseudocode}%
\usepackage{listings}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\graphicspath{ {./figures/} }
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[babel=true]{csquotes}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[varg]{txfonts}
%%%%
\usepackage{lmodern}
% number format
\usepackage{flexisym}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric]{biblatex}
%\usepackage[square, numbers]{natbib}%
\addbibresource{sn-bibliography.bib}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{longtable}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
%\theoremstyle{thmstyleone}%
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}%  meant for continuous numbers
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}% 
%\theoremstyle{thmstyletwo}%
\newtheorem{example}{Example}%
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}%
%\theoremstyle{thmstylethree}%
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}%
\raggedbottom
\begin{document}
some text here. can be anything.
\end{document}


The sn-jnl document class itself loads natbib, and uses the class options to select the required bibliography style — see comments in the Springer Nature sample .tex file on the suitable option to use. In other words, biblatex shouldn't be used with this class.

thanks, when I comment out the biblatex package, it gives me an error and does not even produce the pdf.

@Elika Did you do a "recompile from scratch" after removing biblatex? https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Clearing_the_cache

yes I did, it was not helpful though.
